# Grouping items by time-series bins in Python

Tags: python, binning

I have data that looks like:

```
[[datetime1, label1],
 [datetime2, label2],
 [datetime3, label3]]
```

The labels are strings. I have a binning parameter (delta) that's a datetime.timedelta.

What I'm trying to do:

1. Come up with the set of datetime bins, equally spaced by delta. In other words, below, datetimebin2 - datetimebin1 = datetimebin3 - datetimebin2 = delta .
2. Bin the labels into those bins.

So I would end up with something like:

```
[[datetimebin1, [label1, label2],
 [datetimebin2, []],
 [datetimebin3, []],
 [datetimebin4, [label3]]
```

I've been pointed to pandas, but haven't found what I'm looking for. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean with equally spaced ?

Comment: and datetimebin1 is the datetime object resulting of datetime1 - datetime2. for example?

Comment: Not necessarily. datetimebin1 should be the min of the datetimes in the data. datetimebin2 will be datetimebin1 + delta (where delta is a given parameter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines should do:

```
# data: a lists of lists (length 2) of measurements
# res: resulting list of lists
# delta: time delta

# output list (will be a list of lists, as in the question

res = []
# end of first bin:
binstart = data[0][0]
res.append([binstart, []])

# iterate through the data item
for d in data:
    # if the data item belongs to this bin, append it into the bin
    if d[0] < binstart + delta:
        res[-1][1].append(d[1])
        continue

    # otherwise, create new empty bins until this data fits into a bin
    binstart += delta
    while d[0] > binstart + delta:
        res.append([binstart, [])
        binstart += delta

    # create a bin with the data
    res.append([binstart, [d[1]]])
```

Comment: I should have clarified that the data isn't necessarily sorted. Easy enough to sort it first though; thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think @DrV's is the correct answer, but I've prepared an example trying to show how something similar could be achieved using Pandas:

```
import numpy
import pandas
import datetime
import time

# Binning delta

delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=1)

# Sample data

sample = [
    ['2014-08-09 16:30:00', 'label1'],
    ['2014-08-09 15:30:00', 'label2'],
    ['2014-08-09 14:30:00', 'label3'],
    ['2014-08-09 14:00:00', 'label4']
]

# Create dataframe and append UNIX timestamp column

df = pandas.DataFrame(sample)
df.columns = ['Datetime', 'Label']
df['Datetime'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])
df['UnixStamp'] = df['Datetime'].apply(lambda d: time.mktime(d.timetuple()))
df = df.set_index('Datetime')

# Calculate bins

bins = numpy.arange(min(df['UnixStamp']), max(df['UnixStamp']) + delta.seconds, delta.seconds)

# Group columns by datetime bin

def bin_from_tstamp(tstamp):

    diffs = [abs(tstamp - bin) for bin in bins]
    return bins[diffs.index(min(diffs))]

grouped = df.groupby(df['UnixStamp'].map(
    lambda t: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(bin_from_tstamp(t))
))
```

At this point `grouped` contains the dataset grouped by datetime bins.

The following is the result of printing `grouped.groups` (where the keys are the datetime bins and the values are the grouped datetimes):

```
{
    numpy.datetime64('2014-08-09T18:00:00.000000000+0200'): [
        Timestamp('2014-08-09 16:30:00')
    ], 
    numpy.datetime64('2014-08-09T17:00:00.000000000+0200'): [
        Timestamp('2014-08-09 15:30:00')
    ], 
    numpy.datetime64('2014-08-09T16:00:00.000000000+0200'): [
        Timestamp('2014-08-09 14:30:00'), 
        Timestamp('2014-08-09 14:00:00'
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is great. I'm going to check to see which is going to be faster for my data (this or @DrV 's) and will update.